# Android: How to use OpenGL ES to process camera preview frames on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, gpu

I'm new to OpenGL ES. I need to leverage the power of GPU to process the frames from camera preview. So I guess the only way to do that it's to send the camera preview to OpenGL's texture memory. And then I need to use OpenGL to whitening the image, removing the shadow, scaling, etc. And then send it back to camera preview.

Could anybody give me some hints on how to do this? Any references would be helpful. I cannot find anything on the web.

Thanks,
Charles

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152079/gpgpu-programming-with-opengl-es-2-0/5156845#5156845 - that's an example for iOS, so the part of "how do I get the camera data to a texture" differs for Android; the processing though, can do the same.