# Retrieve the value of gl_FragColor

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

This site([GPGPU programming with OpenGL ES 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152079/gpgpu-programming-with-opengl-es-2-0)) talk about how to use opengl es2.0 to do gpgpu
The problem of mine is how to retrieve the value of 
gl_FragColor back to the cpu site(host)?

fragment shader

```
varying vec2 fragTexCoord;

void main() {        
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, fragTexCoord);
}
```

cpu site

```
 //.......
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

  //How could I get the value after draw?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem of mine is how to retrieve the value of gl_FragColor back to the cpu site(host)?

[`glReadPixels()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml)